# Laravel get row with records above and below it

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a Laravel 4.2 project where I get data from a SQL DB and I can display onto the page. I can select the single record just fine, but I want to also show the records around the one selected.

For example, I want to show the 5 records above and below the one selected. Im not sure how to do this in Laravel.

```
$gradschoolrange = MOGRadschool::where('Title', '=', $gradschool)->get();
```

In the above example $gradschool might be "Test College", it will return that with a value, but I want to show all the other related records around it with those values too. The results should look something like this:

1. ABC College
2. Another College
3. Blah College
4. Go To College
5. **Test College**
6. Yet Another College
7. Yo Yo College
8. College College
9. Something College
10. Eating College

Answer (score 2):

As there's no ordering specified in your initial query, I'm assuming you want 5 next/previous records according to primary key (`id`? - if not, you would obviously need to change that) in the table?

Given that IDs may not be numerically sequential, we can't simply assume that the previous 5 rows will be the ID of the row with title = `$gradschool` minus 5, so wondered if this might work:

```
    $initial = MOGRadschool::where('Title', $gradschool)->first(); // get the initial row with the title of $gradschool
    $result = MOGRadschool::where('id', '<', $initial->id)->take(5)->orderBy('id', 'DESC') // new query getting the previous 5 rows, by ID
        ->union(MOGRadschool::where('id', '>', $initial->id)->take(5)) // union a second query getting the next 5 rows by ID
        ->get() // get the result as a collection
        ->add($initial) // add the initial row to the collection
        ->sort(); // sort the collection (by id) so that the initial row is in the middle
```

So the output is a collection containing the initial row in the middle, with up to 5 records either side. You also have the initial row to highlight the output, if you need that.

Comment: Your solution looks pretty nice **but** there's an issue: Since you don't order the `MOGRadschool::where('id', '<', $initial->id)`, if we send, for example, ID = 329, we would get the **first** five with lower ID, meaning we would get 1,2,3,4,5. You'd have to `->orderBy('id', 'desc')` it to obtain the correct ones, meaning, 328, 327, 326, 325, 324 (all based on an example with sequential IDs)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it based on the IDs, which is what I understand from your issue, something like this should work:

```
$selectedGradSchool = MOGRadschool::where('Title', '=', $gradschool)->get()->first();
$aboveSelected = MOGRadschool::where('id', '<=', $selectedGradSchool->id)
                 ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                 ->take('5')
                 ->get();
$belowSelected = MOGRadschool::where('id', '>' $selectedgradSchool->id)
                 ->take('5')
                 ->get();
//Concatenate both results
$schoolRange = $aboveSelected->concat($belowSelected);
```

Now the collection should look similar to your desired result.

Comment: I know, that'd be the exact number of results (10 including the selected one) he seems to be expecting, so I went for it that way

Comment: I realised that and deleted my comment - apologies :)